# checkboxlist databinding to an entity framework table

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I have placed a checkboxlist in a formview object.
I would like to store and load the results of the checkboxlist in a table of an entity framework.

I filled the cbl with values and labels coming from a table that has 2 columns, using the DataSourceID, DataTextField and DataValueField attributes but I can't seem to find how to bind the cbl to the entity framework object in order to store the checked values when the formview is in "EDIT" mode.

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks!

```
<asp:FormView ID="formView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="Ods1" 
        Height="203px" Width="495px" 
        onpageindexchanging="formView1_PageIndexChanging">
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblProducts" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" 
                Width="782px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="ProductName" 
                DataValueField="ProductCode">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductCode], [ProductName] FROM [Products]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="Ods1" runat="server" 
        DataObjectTypeName="WebApplication1.EDM.Emp" DeleteMethod="DeleteEmp" 
        InsertMethod="CreateNewEmp" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        SelectMethod="GetEmpByEmpId" TypeName="WebApplication1.EDM.EmpLogic" 
        UpdateMethod="UpdateEmp" OnSelecting="Ods1_Selecting">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:RouteParameter Name="EmpId" RouteKey="EmpId" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: @AmiramKorach I've added only the relevant parts of the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:FormView ID="formView1" runat="server" 
     OnItemUpdating="formView1_ItemUpdating" ...>

protected void formView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   var cblProducts = formView1.FindControl("cblProducts") as CheckBoxList;

   foreach (ListItem item in cblProducts.Items)
   {
       if (item.Selected)
       {
           // Check if item.Value is not in the db for this employee, if so add it
       }
       else
       {
           // Check if item.Value is in the db for this employee, if so delete it
       }
   }

   // save
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amiram, but I'm looking for something more generic. I'm using this line in order to update the entity: formView1.UpdateItem(true); and was looking to bind the cbl to the emp object (like I do with textboxes and the Text='<%# Bind("number", "{0:N}") %>' attribute, using bind or eval)

Comment: Binding is about bind a single value to a field (may be many times like in a grid). I don't think this fits here. Maybe you can do that with a very complex mechanism. I don't think it worth the effort.

Comment: Let's say I have a list of 100 products and I want to know which employee knows how to use which product. I can add 100 columns to the employees table, 1 for each product and store a boolean value for each employee (Y,N) and for each product. The problem is that in case a new product arrives, I need to add another column (BAD IDEA). Instead, I'm looking to have 3 tables - employees, products and employees-products. I've built the EDM according to this model and now I'm looking to update it correctly. Update each line of the employee-product table manually would be too slow and error-prone...

Comment: You data design is good, but maybe using a `CheckBoxList` here is not a good idea. It is good when you have few items, not 100. You can also implement that by putting only the employee products in a table, add a delete button for each row, and in the insert template put a textbox with auto-complete for the product name, or open a popup to add a product from a separate list.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but could you please elaborate on this solution since I'm pretty new to ASP.net programming. Which object would you recommend for the table and how to design it? I think that a dropdownbox would be more appropriate for choosing the product. Anyway, I was a bit exaggerating with the 100. It's more like 15-20, so the solution with the cbl is still preferred if it's possible (it's the customer wish as well...)

Comment: You can use a GridView for that

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following;

```
foreach (ListItem chk in cblProducts.Items)
{
    string productId= chk.Value;
    if (IsProductAvailable(productId) // this method will basically goes to database and return true of false
        chk.Selected = true;
    else
        chk.Selected = false;
}


private void IsProductAvailable(string productId)
{
        string query = "SELECT [ProductId] FROM [Product] ";
        query += "WHERE [ProductId] = @ProductId";
        DbCommand comm = new DbCommand();
        comm.CommandText = query;

        DbParameter param = comm.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@ProductId";
        param.Value = productId;
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);

        DataTable table = comm.ExecuteCommand();
        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
}
```

please modify query and parameters according to your need.

Comment: Hi .Net Dreamer, thanks for your answer but please check my comment to Amiram.